# For which positive numbers b is it true that $b^x \geq 1+x$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus

For which positive numbers $b$ is it true that $$b^x \geq 1+x,\forall x ?$$

My calculus teacher gave this question on a test recently, and I’m not sure how to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, that question is essentially the same as this question. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Comment: All answers of the **alleged** duplicates only show that it's the minimal value with that property, not that it is the **only** value. Well, that's bound to happen if questions are too eagerly closed for "educational" rather than mathematical reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $x$, this means $$\frac{b^x-1}{x}\ge1$$ and thus $$\ln b=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{b^x-1}{x}\ge1.$$ For negative $x$, the division by $x$ means the reversion of the inequality, so $$\frac{b^x-1}{x}\le1$$ and thus $$\ln b=\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{b^x-1}{x}\le1.$$ So we have $\ln b=1$ or $b=e$.

Comment: Thank you Professor Vector. You’ve helped me out a lot.

Comment: I think the correct solution should be $b \geq e$.

Comment: No, it only works for $e$.

Comment: if it works for e it has  also to work for every b>e!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate both sides.

Comment: Differentiate both sides and then?

Comment: @gimusi And then, since $(b^x)'=\log(b)b^x$ and since $\log b\geqslant1\iff b\geqslant e$, the derivative at $0$ will be greater than or equal to the derivative of $x+1$ at $0$ if and only if $b\geqslant e$. Since both $b^x$ and $1+x$ take the value $1$ at $0$, you can deduce from this that the inequality $b^x\geqslant1+x$ must fail near $0$ if $b<e$ and it is not hard to prove that it never fails otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: @gimusi I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I’m learning so much math here. It’s very useful and funny! Regards